# HTML Mail on Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, newsletter

i want to create a newsletter compatitable with Outlook. I'm getting a huge gap on the left **only** on Outlook clients. It's written in HTML.

http://www.nikosdelig.com/eurasia-newsletter-russian.html

Comment: How can we fix it if you don't provide any HTML?

Comment: You'll need to supply a screen shot and the HTML to explain the issue before we can help you.

Comment: http://www.nikosdelig.com/eurasia-newsletter-russian.html Code
http://www.nikosdelig.com/2013-03-25%2002.40.37%20pm.png Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In outlook, especially Outlook 2013, you have to specify any table data (`<td>`) which has heigh lower than `12px` by: `style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;"`. For example:

```
<td height="1" bgcolor="#000000" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell me where this line comes in m code?

Comment: Try using tables and inline CSS. You have used p, div, etc which is are not supported in most email clients. go to http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and http://www.campaignmonitor.com/ to learn more

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to debug, I'll offer you a simplified and stable framework to use instead. As you can see, you don't need a lot of the extra stuff you have in your code, particularly the nested tables and `<tbody>` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">           
    /* Client-specific Styles */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#f1f1f1" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="150">
      LOGO
    </td>
    <td width="450" style="padding:20px;">
      HEADER TEXT
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" valign="bottom">
      COLUMN
    </td>
    <td width="450" style="padding:20px;">
      BODY<br>
      ...<br>
      ...<br>
      ...<br>
      ...<br>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: -1? stop trolling through my posts. If you think my answer is wrong, put up or shut up.